# How can I loop over an array from the first occurrence of an element with a specific value using perl?

Tags: arrays, loops, perl

I have an array like ("valueA", "valueB", "valueC", "valueD") etc. I want to loop over the values of the array starting from (for example) the first instance of "valueC". Everything in the array before the first instance of the value "valueC" should be ignored; so in this case only "valueC" and "valueD" would be handled by the loop.

I can just put a conditional inside my loop, but is there a neater way to express the idea using perl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my $seen;
for ( grep $seen ||= ($_ eq "valueC"), @array ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: As with much of Perl, a little terse. Care to explain what this is doing and why it works?

Comment: The `$seen` variable is used as a flag: have I already seen the starting value? `grep` iterates over the array, and if not yet seen, it assigns the result of the comparison to seen. This way, seen will be set to 1 at the first occurence of the valueC and not changed later. Grep will return only those values from `@array` for which `$seen` is true, i.e. 1.

Comment: @DanFego : It could also have been written as `grep { $seen = $seen || $_ eq 'valueC' } @array`. Once `$seen` is set to true, it stays true.

Answer (score 6):

```
my $seen;
for ( @array ) {

    $seen++ if /valueC/;
    next unless $seen;
    ...
}
```

But that `$seen` is a little ungainly. The [flip-flop operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) looks tidier IMO:

```
for ( @array ) {

    next unless /^valueC$/ .. /\0/;
           # or /^valueC$/ .. '' !~ /^$;
           # or $_ eq 'valueC' .. /\0/;
    ...
}
```

Or simply (building on ikegami's suggestion):

```
for ( grep { /^valueC$/ .. /(*FAIL)/ } @array ) { ... }
```

Comment: If you want something that never matches, `/(?!)/` and `/(*FAIL)/` are ideal, but you actually want something false that's not a number constants, so `do{0}` would do.

Comment: @ikegami : Thanks, I was hoping to be enlightened about that. I'm a little surprised that `sub{ 0 }` and `!! 0` don't work.

Comment: @Zaid, `sub { 0 }` returns a code ref that's true -- `sub { 0 }->()` would work -- and `!!0` is a constant.

Answer (score 6):

I think you also need to check if the "valueC" exist inside the array.
Hope this helps.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(first);

my @array = qw(valueA valueB valueC valueD);

my $starting_element = 'valueC';

# make sure that the starting element exist inside the array
# first search for the first occurrence of the $stating_element
# dies if not found
my $starting_index = first { $array[$_] eq $starting_element } 0 .. $#array
    or die "element \"$starting_element\" does not exist inside the array";

# your loop
for my $index ($starting_index .. $#array) {
    print $array[$index]."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

TIMTOWTDI, but I think that:

```
foreach my $item (@list) {
      next if !$seen && ($item ne 'valueC');
      $seen++;
      ...
}
```

is both readable, correct and and terse enough. All the /valueC/ solution will process anything after "DooDadvalueCFuBAr", not what the OP asked. And, no you need no flipflop/range operator, and checking for the existence beforehand is really strange, besides requiring a possibly noncore package to perform a rather trivial task.The grep solution is really making my head spin, besides creating and tossing a temp array as a side effect.

If you want to get fancy and avoid ''ifs':

```
foreach my $item (@list) {
     $seen || ($item eq 'valueC') || next;
     $seen++;
     ...
}
```

Just don't write home about it. :-)

Comment: The flip-flop will still work without the `/valueC/`: `next unless $_ eq 'valueC' .. '' !~ /^$/;` The idea was to introduce the flip-flop construct as a TIMTOWDI alternative, nothing more.

Comment: as for use strict, just add ''my $seen=0;"'' etc, where appropriate (before the loop). The construct stands.

Comment: You don't need `my $seen=0;` as `my $seen;` will work just as well.

Comment: does `next if !$seen || ($item ne 'valueC')` works? I think this will always give you a true value.

Answer (score 2):

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( first_index );

foreach my $item ( @array[ ( first_index { $_ eq 'ValueC' } @array ) .. $#array ] ){
    # process $item
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my $start = 0;
++$start while $start < @array && $array[$start] ne 'valueC';
```

followed by either

```
for (@array[$start..$#array]) {
   say;
}
```

or

```
for my $i ($start..$#array) {
   say $array[$i];
}
```